# themes of kendoui mobile & angular with cordova platform

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile, kendo-ui

how to change the theme of kendoui mobile with angularjs to use ios theme for Android.

Is there a way ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution :

This is the way for  **kendoui mobile with angularjs** .

you can write just **platform="'ios7'"** as attribute

```
<body kendo-mobile-application platform="'ios7'" ng-app="app" >
```

so this is what I am need, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day, was unable to find it on Kendo API document site. they have very limited documents for Kendo + AngulerJS I feel.

Comment: yes the docs for kendo and angularjs is very limited, Especially

Comment: welcome, yes they have very limited, especially in directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the platform when you declare the Application.

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), { platform: 'ios7' });
```

Here is the documentation for forcing a platform
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/application#configuration-platform

-- Edit, forgot about the kendo-mobile-application directives.  If you are using these, you need to specify k-options on the element where you declare the kendo-mobile-application, to an object which has the kendo Application options specified.

```
<div kendo-mobile-application ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController" k-options="appOptions" ...>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.appOptions = { platform: 'ios7' };
```

Documentation http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-layout/angular

Comment: Forgot about the kendo-mobile-application directives.  Updated answer to include that as well.